# how do I display php code before html

Tags: php

I have a simple question, basically I have written some code, I have written some php code to display code before some html after it and then a footer...the problem is that the html is displaying first and then the footer and then the table..
I want the table to display, then html then footer..
here is my code

```
if($orderCount == 0){
echo "<p><strong> No orders pending. Please try again later.</strong></p>";
  }
echo "<table border=\"1\">\n"echo "<tr> <th bgcolor=\"blue\"> Order Summary</th></tr>
 <tr> <th bgcolor=\"blue\"> Title</th>
   <th bgcolor=\"blue\"> Author</th>
    <th bgcolor=\"blue\"> Format</th>
    <th bgcolor=\"blue\"> Price</th>
     </tr>";


    for($i=0;$i<$orderCount;$i++){

echo "<tr>
    <td> $titleArray[$i]</td>

           <td>$authorArray[$i]</td>
                <td>$formatArray[$i]</td>
                    <td> $$priceArray[$i]</td>
                        </tr>";


}
$total = number_format(array_sum($priceArray),2);
echo " <tr>  <td bgcolor=\"blue\"> Total price</td><td>&nbsp</td>   <td>&nbsp</td><td align=\"right\">$$total</td></tr>"


    ?>
      <form action="myform.php" method="post">
      <ul>
       <li>Payment Information</li>

        </ul>
        <label for="customer name">Customer Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="customername" id="customername"> <br />
        <label for="address">Street Address</label>
        <input type="text" name="city" id="city"> <br />
        <label for="state">State</label>        
        <input type="text" name="state" id="state"> <br />
        <label for="zip">Zip Code</label>
        <input type="text" name="zip" id="zip"> <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Confirm Order">

   </form>

</body>
```

Comment: If you close the table tag `</table>` when your done with it, it might work better.

Comment: ...and you're closing the table row `</tr>` after you've printed your first header... You really need to check your open and close tags...

Comment: ...you also have a bunch of double dollar signs, like `$$total`. Is that intentional? You should really try to structure your code better and look thru it to try and catch all errors.

Comment: actually worked by just closing the table tag...thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [ob_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-contents.php) function.

Comment: Why should he use that, if he's actually prints everything out in the correct order? His code is a playground of mismatching HTML-tags and that's nothing ob_get_contents() would fix.

Answer (score 1):

You could just get of php and do html like this

```
 <?php 
      // some php code you had

 ?>
  your html
  <?php 
   // resume php code
 ?>
```